# How to sum rows and keep their name in a dataframe

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I have a data frame with some variables with the same name but different values. I need to sum the values and keep the original values as a separate column.

```
data <- data.frame(cod = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B"),
           values = c(3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5))
 data

 cod   Values 
 A          3
 B          4
 C          5
 A          1
 A          2
 B          5
```

I expect the following, where the original `Values` column is kept the same and the group sum is added as a new column, `Values2`:

```
> data2
 cod   Values Values2
 A          3       6
 B          4       9
 C          5       5
 A          1       6
 A          2       6
 B          5       9
```

Comment: Try `data$Values2 <- with(data, ave(Values, cod, FUN = sum))` or `library(dplyr); data %>% group_by(cod) %>% mutateValues2 = sum(Values))`

Comment: I tried the first one, and its work very well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `base R` would be

```
data$Values2 <- with(data, ave(Values, cod, FUN = sum))
```